# Change the NAT setttings on mobile dongle

Tags: modem, nat, broadband, dongle

Is it possible to change the NAT type on a mobile dongle modem? I've searched the web but couldn't find anything. Should I contact the ISP for this, is it even possible. At the moment it is set as strict and I want to change it to open.

Answer (score 0):

The NAT configuration is controlled by the mobile broadband provider's infrastructure setup. There's no way for you to change it.